When to reintroduce a cat and dog after fight?
My fiancé's dog (rowlf) and my cat (Nala) have been best of friends since day 1 of meeting each-other. Never had any issues when we started living together and were the best of friends.
However, about a month ago when Rowlf and Nala were play chasing up and down the hallway while I was working in my home office, I didn’t see what happened but whatever it was, it set Nala off. She attacked rowlf. Puffed up, hissing, growling, scratching, jumping on him…you name it. Completely out of character for her, she’s always been around dogs and never has been the only animal. So we shortly split them up and things were getting better but still not 100% there still was tension.
Fast forward to about a few days ago. I was returning to work in my office and Nala followed me in. Rowlf shortly followed after to sleep on the guest bed next to my desk like he always did. As soon as he was at the door, Nala snapped and attacked him once again. Broke up the fight and they've been split up ever since.
Also, both fights Rowlf is not fighting at all, he’s just trying to get away from her but she’s not letting it happen.
I’ve established my home office as her safe space. Going forward there will be a baby gate up so Rowlf can’t be in there at all and she has an escape from him. They’ve been getting sniffs in under the door but I just don’t trust Nala right now. I let her roam the house at night while we sleep and she hangs out with me in the office during the day with everything she needs.
When would be a good time to reintroduce? It’s been about 3 days now but my fiancé is out of town. I’d rather wait until she returns and not rush it.
I don’t think she’s hurt because she’s not expressing any sort of discomfort and acting completely normal unless she sees rowlf. The only possible thing is maybe she’s anxious? I noticed she was shaking when rowlf was near the door one day. Maybe I should cross off a vet visit just to be safe? I don’t want to medicate her but maybe some anxiety treatment might help. I have the feliway diffusers and spray but it’s not doing anything.
It’s hard coming home not hanging out with both of them but I guess this will take some time and we just gotta be patient
I appreciate any other tips and tricks.

Sudden changes in behavior and especially sudden aggression can be a sign of possble medical problems like pain caused by arthritis, a UTI or any number of other causes. A vet visit is definitely in order.
